# Store values to List and pass that list to another form

Tags: c#, .net

I have two tables:

`tblUserType` with columns: `colTypeId` and `colTypeName`

and

`tblUsers` with columns: `colUserName`, `coltypeId`

When user want's to delete type from db and that type Id is in use (foreign key), I want to display confirmation window with information on users that have that type id.

for example

```
int exist = this.tblUsersTableAdapter1.FillByTypeId(appDataSet.tblUsers, typeId);
if (exist >= 1)
      {
         foreach (DataRow dr in appDataSet.tblUsers.Rows)
             {
                // string userName = dr["colUserName"].ToString();
                // show message box once but with all username (stringBuilder.Append)
                // or better, create List and pass List to another form
                // for displaying List in listbox
             }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

var nameList = (from dr in appDataSet.tblUsers.Rows
                select dr["colUserName"].ToString()).ToList();

to get the list of names...